# Android - I cant go to next activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, database-design

This is my logcat. I am trying from so many days and unable to resolve the errors.

```
com.example.project E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.project, PID: 5761
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:402)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5305)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5305) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.EditText com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.getEditText()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.project.SignUp.validateFullName(SignUp.java:110)
        at com.example.project.SignUp.call2ndSignUpScreen(SignUp.java:50)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5305) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

THIS IS MY SIGNUP ACTIVITY. FROM THIS ACTIVITY I WANTED TO MOVE TO 2ND SIGNUP ACTIVITY. ITS CODE IS GIVEN BELOW THE SIGNUP CLASS CODE.

```
package com.example.project;

import android.app.ActivityOptions;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.util.Pair;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;


public class SignUp extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView backBtn;
    Button next, login;
    TextView titleText;
    TextInputLayout fullname, username, email, password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);


        backBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.singup_back_btn);
        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.singup_next_btn);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.singup_login_btn);
        titleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.signup_title_text);


    fullname = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.signup_fullname);
    username = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.signup_username);
    email = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.signup_email);
    password = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.signup_password);


    }

    public void call2ndSignUpScreen(View view) {

        if (!validateFullName() | !validateUserName() | !validateEmail() | !validatePassword()) {
            return;
        }


        String fullName =fullname.getEditText().getText().toString();
        String userName =username.getEditText().getText().toString();
        String Email =email.getEditText().getText().toString();
        String Password =password.getEditText().getText().toString();
        UserHelperClass helperclass = new UserHelperClass();

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Users");

        myRef.setValue(helperclass);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignUp2ndClass.class);

        intent.putExtra("fullname", fullName);
        intent.putExtra("username", userName);
        intent.putExtra("email", Email);
        intent.putExtra("password", Password);


        Pair[] pairs = new Pair[4];
        pairs[0] = new Pair<View, String>(next, "transition_back_btn");
        pairs[1] = new Pair<View, String>(next, "transition_title_text");
        pairs[2] = new Pair<View, String>(next, "transition_next_btn");
        pairs[3] = new Pair<View, String>(next, "transition_login_btn");


        ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(SignUp.this, pairs);
        startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
    }


    public void callstartupscreen(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StartUpScreen.class);

        Pair[] pairs = new Pair[1];
        pairs[0] = new Pair<View, String>(findViewById(R.id.singup_back_btn), "signup_transition_back_btn");

        ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(SignUp.this, pairs);
        startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
    }

    public void callLoginScreen(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LogIn.class);

        Pair[] pairs = new Pair[1];
        pairs[0] = new Pair<View, String>(findViewById(R.id.singup_login_btn), "transition_login_btn");

        ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(SignUp.this, pairs);
        startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
    }

    private boolean validateFullName() {

        String val = fullname.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

        if (val.isEmpty()) {
            fullname.setError("Field can not be Empty");
            return false;
        } else {
            fullname.setError(null);
            fullname.setErrorEnabled(false);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private boolean validateUserName() {

        String val = username.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        String checkspaces = "\\A\\w{1,20}\\z";

        if (val.isEmpty()) {
            username.setError("Field can not be Empty");
            return false;
        } else if (val.length() > 20) {
            username.setError("Username is too large");
            return false;
        } else if (!val.matches(checkspaces)) {
            username.setError("No white spaces are allowed!");
            return false;
        } else {
            username.setError(null);
            username.setErrorEnabled(false);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private boolean validateEmail() {

        String val = email.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        String checkEmail = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";

        if (val.isEmpty()) {
            email.setError("Field can not be Empty");
            return false;
        } else if (!val.matches(checkEmail)) {
            email.setError("Invalid Email!");
            return false;
        } else {
            email.setError(null);
            email.setErrorEnabled(false);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private boolean validatePassword() {

        String val = password.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        String checkPassword = "^" +
                "(?=.*[a-zA-Z])" +
                "(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])" +
                ".{4,}" +
                "$";

        if (val.isEmpty()) {
            password.setError("Field can not be Empty");
            return false;
        } else if (!val.matches(checkPassword)) {
            password.setError("Password is weak Try another one!");
            return false;
        } else {
            password.setError(null);
            password.setErrorEnabled(false);
            return true;
        }
    }


}
```

This is my 2nd signup activity.I cannot move to this actvity by clicking on the button which has an onclick function in its xml file.All the other buttons are working which i added in my whole project.i have 3 in total signup activities after i click the next button in my last signup activity the data will be saved inn the firebase. but unfirtunately i cant move forward from my 1st signup activity.

```
package com.example.project;

import android.app.ActivityOptions;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Pair;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class SignUp2ndClass extends AppCompatActivity {


    ImageView backBtn;
    Button next, login;
    TextView titleText;

    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    RadioButton selectGender;
    DatePicker datePicker;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up2nd_class);



        backBtn = findViewById(R.id.singup2_back_button);
        next = findViewById(R.id.singup2_next_button);
        login = findViewById(R.id.singup2_login_btn);
        titleText = findViewById(R.id.signup2_title_text);
        radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
        datePicker = findViewById(R.id.age_picker);

    }


    public void call3rdSignUpScreen(View view) {

        if(!validateGender()){
            return;
        }

        selectGender =findViewById(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        String _gender = selectGender.getText().toString();
        int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
        int month = datePicker.getMonth();
        int year = datePicker.getYear();

        String _date = day+"/"+month+"/"+year;
        String fullname = getIntent().getStringExtra("fullname");
        String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
        String email = getIntent().getStringExtra("email");
        String password = getIntent().getStringExtra("password");

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignUp3rdClass.class);

        Pair[] pairs = new Pair[4];
        pairs[0] = new Pair<View, String>(next, "transition_back_btn");
        pairs[1] = new Pair<View, String>(next, "transition_title_text");
        pairs[2] = new Pair<View, String>(next, "transition_next_btn");
        pairs[3] = new Pair<View, String>(next, "transition_login_btn");


        ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(SignUp2ndClass.this, pairs);
        startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
    }


    private boolean validateGender(){

        if(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()==-1){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Select Gender", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void callLoginScreen (View view){

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LogIn.class);

        Pair[] pairs = new Pair[1];
        pairs[0] = new Pair<View, String>(findViewById(R.id.singup2_login_btn),"transition_login_btn");

        ActivityOptions options=ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(SignUp2ndClass.this,pairs);
        startActivity(intent,options.toBundle());
    }

}
```

Comment: You'll want to put a breakpoint on `fullname = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.signup_fullname);` then run in a debugger, and see if the breakpoint hits, and if the line then finds the view correctly.

Comment: Post your layout file for `activity_sign_up.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialized any of the TextInputLayout fullname, username, email and password in the SignUp activity.

Comment: what should i initilize them ?

Comment: Intialize them like `fullname = findViewById(R.id.fullname);` where fullname in R.id.fullname is the id of TextInputLayout in your XML code.